# Executar um SELECT JOIN com condição para diferentes tabelas

Tags: php, sql

Estou fazendo um sistema de `ticket` onde possuo a tabela de mensagens de cada `ticket`. Essa mensagem pode ser enviada tanto por um administrador como pelo usuário que abriu o `ticket`.

Com isso, estou com o problema na hora de obter o nome do usuário, seja ele um administrador ou o usuário que abriu o `ticket`, pois seus registros estão em tabelas diferentes (`tabela_admin`, `tabela_usuario`).

---

A primeira opção que tentei utilizar foi a seguinte:

```
//Estrutura da tabela ticket_mensagem
id  |  ticket_id  |  usuario_id  |  usuario_tipo  |  data_criado

//outro sql obtêm os dados gerais do ticket
SELECT a.*, b.nome
FROM ticket_mensagem a 
LEFT JOIN tabela_admin   b ON a.usuario_id = b.id AND a.usuario_tipo = 1
LEFT JOIN tabela_usuario b ON a.usuario_id = b.id AND a.usuario_tipo = 2
WHERE a.ticket_id = '$ticket_id'
```

Obviamente ele não funcionou, mas a ideia é que eu selecione o `nome` ou da tabela `tabela_admin` ou `tabela_empresa` de acordo com o `usuario_tipo`.

---

A segunda opção, seria salvar na tabela ticket_mensagem ou o id do admin ou da empresa, deixando o outro como null, segue exemplo:

```
//Estrutura da tabela ticket_mensagem
id  |  ticket_id  |  admin_id  |  usuario_id  |  data_criado
1   |      1      |    NULL    |     2        |   .....
2   |      1      |    4       |     NULL     |   .....

//outro sql obtêm os dados gerais do ticket
SELECT a.*, b.nome, c.nome
FROM chamado_msg a 
LEFT JOIN tabela_admin   b ON a.admin_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tabela_usuario c ON a.usuario_id = c.id
WHERE a.id_ticket = '$id_ticket'
```

---

O problema é que nenhuma das opções está funcionando e, como essa não é muito minha área, não sei mais como proceder ou decidir qual das opções é a melhor para obter esse resultado e corrigi-las.

Se houver outro meio, algo mais simples ou outro método que seja o correto, não tem problema em alterar. O importante é obter o resultado final, que seria obter o nome do respectivo "usuário", seja ele administrador ou usuário.

Comment: Qual BD está usando?

Comment: @Ricardo Estou usando mysql

Comment: Editei minha resposta e coloquei um link para o [fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece81f/3/0) funcionando com IF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após alguns testes e algumas tentativas com base nas 2 primeiras respostas, já que nenhuma resolveu o problema diretamente, apenas me guiaram para o resultado final, este foi o código final que utilizei e acabou resolvendo o meu problema:

```
SELECT 
    a.*,    
    IF(a.tp_usuario = 1,  b.nome, c.nome) as 'nome'
FROM ticket_mensagem a, tabela_admin b, tabela_empresa c
WHERE a.id_ticket = '$id_ticket'
```

O problema do uso do `CASE` é que ele retornava TODOS os dados das tabelas `*_admin`ou `*_empresa`, enquanto que eu só precisava do nome.

Já o problema na resposta com o uso do `if` é que ele não pegava o `nome admin` ou o `nome empresa`. Ele pegava somente o `nome admin` ou o `nome empresa`, mas somente se o `nome admin` fosse nulo.

Não era essa a verificação que eu queria.

Eu precisava pegar o `nome admin` se o `tp_usuario` fosse 1, ou pegar o `nome empresa` se o `tp_usuario` fosse 2. Portanto a minha resposta final está funcionando dentro desses requisitos.

Answer (score 1):

Para MySql você poderia fazer um IF no Select:

```
IF(ISNULL(b.nome), c.nome, b.nome) as nome
```

Não tenho certeza absoluta sobre a sintaxe, mas o IF no select pode resolver de maneira fácil.

ATUALIZANDO.

Troquei o sql acima para ISNULL().
Aqui tem um exemplo funcionando: [Fiddler](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ece81f/3/0)

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      nome varchar(20) default null,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id)
                      );

CREATE TABLE administrador (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      nome varchar(20) default null,
                      PRIMARY KEY (id)
                      );

INSERT INTO cliente(id, nome) values (1, null);
INSERT INTO cliente(id, nome) values  (2, "Ricardo");

INSERT INTO administrador(id, nome) values (1, "Daniel");
INSERT INTO administrador(id, nome) values  (2, null);


select 
IF(ISNULL(c.nome), a.nome, c.nome) as nome
from cliente c,
administrador a
where c.id = a.id
and c.id = 1
```

Comment: Mas o nome deles nunca vai ser nulo. Acho que você não compreendeu. Eu preciso pegar o nome do usuário dependendo de quem inseriu aquela resposta ao ticket. Ex.: Se foi um usuario do tipo 1 (adm) eu obtenho da tabela `tabela_admin` e se for do tipo 2 (usuario cliente) eu obtenho da `tabela_usuario`. Mas não obter um ou outro se algum for nulo.

Comment: Em vez de testar a coluna nome testa a coluna tipo na tabela de mensagem: `IF(m.tipo = 1, a.nome, c.nome) as nome`

Answer (score 1):

Faça um **CASE**:

```
SELECT ticket_mensagem.*, 
       CASE WHEN ticket_mensagem.usuario_tipo = 1
            THEN tabela_admin.nome
            ELSE tabela_usuario.nome
       END  AS nome
FROM ticket_mensagem  
LEFT JOIN tabela_admin   ON tabela_admin.id = ticket_mensagem.usuario_id
                         AND ticket_mensagem.usuario_tipo = 1
LEFT JOIN tabela_usuario ON tabela_usuario.id = ticket_mensagem.usuario_id
                         AND ticket_mensagem.usuario_tipo = 2
WHERE ticket_mensagem.ticket_id = '$ticket_id'
```

Comment: O seu código está quase funcionando. Estava com alguns erros de syntax e uma lógica. Mudei para isso: `SELECT *, CASE WHEN ticket_mensagem.usuario_tipo = 1` e está obtendo os dados respectivos corretamente. Porém, ele não obtém somente o nome, ele está pegando TODOS os dados da tabela `tabela_admin` ou `tabela_usuario` (dependendo da verificação). Ex.: o admin vem o nome, email, telefone, etc.. E o usuario também vem com nome, cpf, endereço, etc.. Como prevenir isso e obter somente o nome?